# In my Flutter Project, I want to customize the font of a text, but it doesn't work

Tags: android, flutter, fonts

This is the pubspec.yaml. I defined the fonts that I am going to use and I copied the font file to fonts directory of my android project.

```yaml
name: your_flutter_app
description: A new Flutter project
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  math_expressions: ^2.0.0  # Add this line to include the math_expressions package
flutter:
 fonts:
   - family: My-font
     fonts:
       - asset: fonts/Yarndings20Charted-regular.ttf
```

And this is my main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold (
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('my First App'),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber.shade100,
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: Text(
          'I am  Haroon',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
            color: Colors.green,
            fontFamily: 'My-font',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      child: Text('click'),
      onPressed: () {
        //Something Here;
      },
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    ),
  ),
));
```

I used pub.get and update dependencies. But none worked!

Comment: Stop the app if it is running, Check the file name, for example it might be `Yarndings20Charted-Regular.ttf` instead of `Yarndings20Charted-regular.ttf`, then start the app.

Answer (score 0):

There might some cases:

1. Ensure that the font file (Yarndings20Charted-regular.ttf) is
   located in the correct directory within your Flutter project.
2. Double-check that the family name specified in your pubspec.yaml
   matches the actual family name embedded in the font file.
3. Sometimes, changes to the pubspec.yaml file may not take effect
   immediately. Try hot-reloading your app by pressing **r** in the
   terminal or restarting your app to see if the font is loaded
   correctly.
4. Sometimes, cached assets may cause issues with font loading. You can
   try clearing the Flutter build cache by running flutter clean in
   your terminal and then rebuilding your app.